# Group by column and resampled date and get rolling sum of other column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following data:

```
(Pdb) df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['SE0000195570','SE0000195570','SE0000195570','SE0000195570','SE0000191827','SE0000191827','SE0000191827','SE0000191827', 'SE0000191827'],'val': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8', '9'],'date': pd.to_datetime(['2014-10-23','2014-07-16','2014-04-29','2014-01-31','2018-10-19','2018-07-11','2018-04-20','2018-02-16','2018-12-29'])})

(Pdb) df1
             id val       date
0  SE0000195570   1 2014-10-23
1  SE0000195570   2 2014-07-16
2  SE0000195570   3 2014-04-29
3  SE0000195570   4 2014-01-31
4  SE0000191827   5 2018-10-19
5  SE0000191827   6 2018-07-11
6  SE0000191827   7 2018-04-20
7  SE0000191827   8 2018-02-16
8  SE0000191827   9 2018-12-29
```

**UPDATE:**
As per the suggestions of @user3483203 I have gotten a bit further but not quite there. I've amended the example data above with a new row to illustrate better.

```
(Pdb) df2.assign(calc=(df2.dropna()['val'].groupby(level=0).rolling(4).sum().shift(-3).reset_index(0, drop=True)))
                                   id  val       date  calc
id           date                                          
SE0000191827 2018-02-28  SE0000191827    8 2018-02-16  26.0
             2018-03-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-04-30  SE0000191827    7 2018-04-20  27.0
             2018-05-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-06-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-07-31  SE0000191827    6 2018-07-11   NaN
             2018-08-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-09-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-10-31  SE0000191827    5 2018-10-19   NaN
             2018-11-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2018-12-31  SE0000191827    9 2018-12-29   NaN
SE0000195570 2014-01-31  SE0000195570    4 2014-01-31  10.0
             2014-02-28           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-03-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-04-30  SE0000195570    3 2014-04-29   NaN
             2014-05-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-06-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-07-31  SE0000195570    2 2014-07-16   NaN
             2014-08-31           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-09-30           NaN  NaN        NaT   NaN
             2014-10-31  SE0000195570    1 2014-10-23   NaN
```

For my requirements, the row (SE0000191827, 2018-03-31) should have a calc value since it has four consecutive rows with a value. Currently the row is being removed with the `dropna` call and I can't figure out how to solve that problem.

---

### What I need

**Calculations:** The dates in my initial data is quarterly dates. However, I need to transform this data into monthly rows ranging between the first and last date of each `id` and for each month calculate the sum of the four closest consecutive rows of the input data within that `id`. That's a mouthful. This led me to `resample`. See expected output below. I need the data to be grouped by both id and the monthly dates.

**Performance:** The data I'm testing on now is just for benchmarking but I will need the solution to be performant. I'm expecting to run this on upwards of 100k unique `id`s which may result in around 10 million rows. (100k ids, dates range back up to 10 years, 10years * 12months = 120 months per id, 100k*120 = 12million rows).

### What I've tried

```
(Pdb) res = df.groupby('id').resample('M',on='date')
(Pdb) res.first()
                                   id  val       date
id           date                                    
SE0000191827 2018-02-28  SE0000191827    8 2018-02-16
             2018-03-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-04-30  SE0000191827    7 2018-04-20
             2018-05-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-06-30           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-07-31  SE0000191827    6 2018-07-11
             2018-08-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-09-30           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-10-31  SE0000191827    5 2018-10-19
SE0000195570 2014-01-31  SE0000195570    4 2014-01-31
             2014-02-28           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-03-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-04-30  SE0000195570    3 2014-04-29
             2014-05-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-06-30           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-07-31  SE0000195570    2 2014-07-16
             2014-08-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-09-30           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-10-31  SE0000195570    1 2014-10-23
```

This data looks very nice for my case since it's nicely grouped by `id` and has the `date`s nicely lined up by month. Here it seems like I could use something like  `df['val'].rolling(4)` and make sure it skips `NaN` values and put that result in a new column.

Expected output (new column `calc`):

```
                                   id  val       date  calc
id           date                                    
SE0000191827 2018-02-28  SE0000191827    8 2018-02-16    26
             2018-03-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-04-30  SE0000191827    7 2018-04-20   NaN
             2018-05-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-06-30           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-07-31  SE0000191827    6 2018-07-11   NaN
             2018-08-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-09-30           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2018-10-31  SE0000191827    5 2018-10-19   NaN
SE0000195570 2014-01-31  SE0000195570    4 2014-01-31    10
             2014-02-28           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-03-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-04-30  SE0000195570    3 2014-04-29   NaN
             2014-05-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-06-30           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-07-31  SE0000195570    2 2014-07-16   NaN
             2014-08-31           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-09-30           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-10-31  SE0000195570    1 2014-10-23   NaN
             2014-11-30           NaN  NaN        NaT
             2014-12-31  SE0000195570    1 2014-10-23   NaN
```

Here the result in `calc` is 26 for the first date since it adds the three preceding  (8+7+6+5). The rest for that `id` is NaN since four values are not available.

### The problems

While it may look like the data is grouped by `id` and `date`, it seems like it's actually grouped by `date`. I'm not sure how this works. I need the data to be grouped by id and date.

```
(Pdb) res['val'].get_group(datetime.date(2018,2,28))
7    6.730000e+08
Name: val, dtype: object
```

The result of the `resample` above returns a `DatetimeIndexResamplerGroupby` which doesn't have `rolling`...

```
(Pdb) res['val'].rolling(4)
*** AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResamplerGroupby' object has no attribute 'rolling'
```

---

What to do? My guess is that my approach is wrong but after scouring the documentation I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Looks like your data do not have repeated months, do you need to resample?

Comment: @QuangHoang The input data is what my script currently receives, and I need to output it on a format where I have one row for each month from the earliest to the latest month for each `id`. Resampling was the method I came up with to add these extra rows, do you have a better one?